# Having error while executing the flutter app

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "/home/nujoom/AndroidStudioProjects/notify/android/gradlew" exited abnormally:
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/nujoom/AndroidStudioProjects/notify/android/app/build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 4.10.2. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /home/nujoom/AndroidStudioProjects/notify/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s
  Command: /home/nujoom/AndroidStudioProjects/notify/android/gradlew app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the settings in `android->gradle->wrapper>gradle-wrapper.properties`

Update your `distributionUrl` with `5.4.1` version.

As shown in the image

[image]

and you are good to go.

Comment: @NJNujoom Did you synced gradle properly?
You should sync it by opening android module in android studio.

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: @NJNujoom Right click on android folder, goto flutter and you'll see the option android project in android studio.